# C++ struct vs Class in terms of memory

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have recently come across a question in one of my interview.

What is the difference between C++ struct & class in terms of memory ??

I know they are same in all aspects except access specifiers while inheriting & in case of member variables.

Apart from this is there a real difference in terms of memory (may be memory allocation or destruction or memory management whatever) ????

Edit:
I am not pretty sure why did the interviewer asks this question when there is no difference. I have found similar question [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-76/)  see the 2nd comment down to that link, he is asking a same question but no answer. I think there should be a diff.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: No difference what so ever.

Comment: I am not pretty sure why did the interviewer asks this question when there is no difference. I have found similar question [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-76/)  see the 2nd comment down to that link, he is asking a same question but no answer. I think there should be a diff.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, a `class` and a `struct` are completly identical except for the facts that `struct`s default to `public` access and inheritance whereas `class` defaults to `private`.

As far as memory layout there is no difference what-so-ever.